# All upsells products are not showing on product view/details page

Tags: magento-1.8, product-view, up-sells, slider

I am facing strange issue with usells products selected for a product.
I have selected 11 products as upsells out of one is disabled so total 10 products as in screen shot
[image]
 but in product view page it showing only 6 products.
[image]
I have tried following things to correct it

1 ) Ensure all products are set to enabled

2 ) Check that the products are set to In Stock or that they have manage stock set to "no"

3 ) Ensure products are set to visibility of "Catalog, Search"

4 ) Check that products are assigned to active categories

5 ) If on a multi store setup ensure that products are available on the store view you are reviewing

6 ) Go to System>Index Management select all re-index (you could reindex individually but reindexing it all won't hurt)

7 ) If you are running a 3rd party cache flush these as well. (note: most full page caches will not cache catalog/product pages)

Note: My application has 3 website and two store views, so I checked the website tab also

website tab screenshot:
[image]

Can anyone faced this kind of issue before. ?

Answer (score 1):

go your theme `catalog.xml` on line `205` change the limit

```
<action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
```

Comment: I already set it to 24 `<action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>24</limit></action>`

Comment: did you refresh the cache after that.

Comment: Yes, I did. reindexed all.

Comment: check on magento default theme limit  is working?

Comment: Its not about limit because I am able display 20 products but some product are missing as I stated in my question

Comment: did they display on category page?

Comment: yes, I can purchase those products

Comment: @Charlie product may be disabled or out of stock etc

Answer (score 0):

Try adding cross-sells, up-sells to another category. For example, if your cross-sell product is in LapTop subcategory, add it to its main Category (Computers) as well, or create another category altogether, for example Offers and add it to it. Somehow it worked for me.